# How to get command line args from a pid?

Tags: windows, api, winapi, command-line, process

I've an application which contains pid of another process running on the system. I would want to get the command line args with which the other process was launched using Win32 API.
I have gone through all process related functions and PSAPI functions too but couldn't find one.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Kannan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How do I get the command line of another process?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091125-00/?p=15923)

> Win32 doesn’t expose a process’s command line to other processes.
>
> ...
>
> If you look around in WMI, you’ll find a Win32_Process object, and lo and behold, it has a CommandLine property.

Task manager just uses an undocumented set of APIs in NTDLL instead of using the supported ToolHelp API and PSAPI functions. [Process Hacker](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/) probably does the same and it is open source so you could look at that.

Comment: I tried this on Windows Server 2016, and it only worked partially: it listed all running executables, but the command line of each was "null". Might be something to do with this being Win32 and recent windows versions being 64 bit?